# How to compile program for Arm processor using MingW for Windows?

Tags: c++, c, arm, mingw

I have a device that runs with Arm(Risc) CPU and I like to write program for it. Transferring binary to this device is easy but I cannot simply put com/exe files compiled in windows in this device.

I don't have a clue how can I compile a program to generate an Risc processor bin file (byte order, stack and memory architecture).

I am writing my code in C/C++ and I would like to know how can I compile for Arm/Risc?

This device starts running bin file from position 0 of the file (I believe it is like com files for MS-Dos)

Comment: It is Arm9, Title was wrong and I fixed it. It does not have a famous OS, it starts running bin file from position 0 of file

Comment: Ok, so it has a filesystem or you just upload the binary image on its flash? It has *some* OS or your code has to run "on the bare metal"? What device is it exactly?

Comment: It's quite a broad topic and will vary depending on the exact CPU part type. You're probably best to go looking for an existing sample project for the specific part / board you're using.

Comment: As far as I know its OS is very basic. it only accepts one single file. I transfer it via Serial port and it puts it in designated memory location and after I send finish instruction `0x03 0x03 0x03 0x03` it starts running it. however I didn't manage to run a single bin file on it yet except pre-compiled bins that comes with device.

Comment: @BobSort: so probably it's just some kind of bootloader... still, as PeterJ said, with so little information it's difficult to give you any useful indication... you should really look into the development kit or whatever the vendor provides to build anything for this platform.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, thanks for your replies. Actually I'm more interested in compiling part. Is there any general tool or option for MingW to compile C program for Arm processors?

Comment: @BobSort: you can't use an x86 compiler to build for ARM, but you can build your version of gcc to cross-compile for ARM; see e.g. [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HostedCrossCompilerHOWTO) (although probably you can find on the Internet precompiled binaries). By the way, then you should somehow tell the compiler to emit "the raw code", without putting it in ELF format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to look at [GNU Arm](http://www.gnuarm.com/files.html) website.
It has binaries for compiling for ARM processor in Windows platform. However as Matteo explained in comments, you will need a tool to change `ELF format` to Raw format that you desire.

Comment: Too bad the last update on that site is from 2006 :-(
The binaries don't have any support for cortex-m0, for instance.

Comment: And now the website is dead. But you can buy the domain name if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of MS Visual Studio provide an ARM compiler. But the set of libraries is pretty limited (static CRT and MSVCRT). Also the win32 headers might miss ARM specific definitions. Here's a thread talking about how to enable ARM support in VS: http://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25956
If you want to compile simple command line apps, you might be lucky, for GUI apps, you will need to create your own libs and possibly modify headers or use your own header set. You can have a look at ReactOS, which provides basic ARM support (using VS11+ command line). You might be able to use it to generate the required import libraries. For missing ARM specific header definitions etc. you can always contact ReactOS developers and if you are lucky they will find time to fix it :)